# changes PDF page with webbrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, browser

'm loading pdf files with a web browser. When I load a file I can indicate the opening page using the code:

```
Webb.Navigate(path + "#page=2");
```

but after loading document how do you change the page programmatically?

Comment: i created a combobox as an index to the document. So when combo's value change, i need change the page. Using pdf control i just write: pdfcontrol.setCurrentPage(x); but i don't know how to do this with webbrowser

Answer (score 0):

You would do the same thing as you are doing now.

When your combobox index changes do the following:

```
Webb.Navigate(path + "#page=" + combobox1.Text));
```

Comment: you know another way without reload file? I'm worried about the speed because the system will be networked

Comment: Not with out either wrapping the adobe COM object or doing some sort of fancy send keys message to the browser control.